# Проблема с размерами изображений

Tags: unity3d, изображения

Есть картинка `0.jpg` ее вес: `109 кб`, размер: `1920x1080`.
Когда закидываю в `Unity`, показывает вес `5.9 мб`, это как понимать?

Когда навожу на картинку в `Unity`, мне в конце показывает:

> Only POT textures can be compressed to ETC1 format

Сколько не пытался искать про этот формат, ни как не пойму, что нужно сделать то?

Если я пытаюсь в вкладке `Import Settings -> Android Settings`
Пытаюсь поставить `ETC1`, сжатие, мне пишет:

> Cannot compress to ETC1. The split alpha channel and compression to
>   ETC1 requires a packing tag.

Помогите разобраться, что нужно сделать с картинкой, чтобы она весила столько же сколько и должна?

Я вообще не понимаю, как мне такой формат конвертнуть и что нужно вообще сделать?
Главное, чтобы качество не потерялось, а то иначе это бессмысленность какая-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова `качество` и `.jpg` ставить рядом это преступление.

Несмотря на то, что формат остаётся `.jpg`, при импорте юнити меняет кодировку с сжатой на что-то вроде `.png`, только хуже, отсуда и вес. С сжатой версии работать в реальном времени не возможно, там нет записей о пикселях, её ещё расшифровывать и реконструировать нужно, поэтому с `.jpg` в реал-тайм рендере вообще дел не имеют. Собственно она весит ровно "столько же сколько и должна" на самом деле. Если картинка будет изначально в `.png` весить будет меньше.

POT (Power Of Two) длина и ширина картинки должна быть кратна двум.

Что касается второго сообщения, [на](https://translate.google.com/) и [на](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/SpritePacker.html) тебе в помощь.

П.C. ты в принципе хренью страдаешь. Атласные паки для объединения множества мелких картинок в одну, это экономит `draw call` при рендеринге, а не ради веса. Вес уменьшается только в специализированном совте... графические редакторы и текстурпаки. А с одной большой картинкой без толку, в этом нет смысла.

Comment: Таких картинок 100 штук  и более...

Comment: Ну вообще не соглашусь с размером, атласные паки довольно неплохо размер экономят, если речь про телефоны, где это прям важно.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker а я и не писал, что не экономят.

Comment: Вы написали, цитирую, "не ради веса". Я лишь подметил, что вес решает наравне с экономией вызовов отрисовки.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, вам не кажется, что делать из `100` картинок, размерами `1920х1080` в 1 файл спрайт, это будет гониво полное! К тому-же, эти картинки используются в анимации, то есть 100 картинок это лишь секвенция которая по кадрам закидывается в `Animator`. А вы предлагаете сделать 1... это вообще жутко аж становится, что там будет за картинка...

Comment: @Vendor то, что вы fullhd спрайты мало того, что используете, так ещё и анимируете ими сцену - вот это ужас.

Comment: У тебя не с размером изображения проблемы, а с головой! Покайся! В памяти под изображение резервируется не его натуральный размер в пикселях а 2/4/8/16/32/64/128/256/512/1024/... и тд. И тут текстурные атласы правельных размеров сильно экономят аперативу. Атласы 8k-16k это уже бред, а на твой франкенштейн памяти не хватит.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, Какое правильное разрешение использовать для того. чтобы экран весь заполнило? Чтобы она на все экраны подходила... Посоветуйте, что - то.

Comment: @Vendor, вы знаете, после ваших "гониво полное" (и первоначальную версию последнего коммента я тоже видел) у меня нет желания вам хоть как-то помогать, уж извините.

Comment: Ему тут чуть ли не всю мат часть по картинке расписали, а он пишет "гониво полное"... lol... ну и кент. И такие бывают, куда же без них.

Comment: То есть из 100 картинок, сделать 1 это номрально? Это что-же за размеры будут картинки такие.... О боге, даже если и уменьшить до `1024x576` и завернуть все картинки в 1, будет размер `94208x52992` - это нормальное явление?)))

Comment: В памяти это дерьмо займёт 131.072x65.536, что примерно 10 в 9 степени пикселей. Допустим ты ужал картинки, вес 16 bit пикселя без aplha канала 48 bit. В памяти это уже займёт 1 гиг.

Comment: Я немного просто не понимаю, что есть что, но это нормально. что я сейчас сделал? Я уменьшил до 1024 и сделал все 100 штук в 1 атлас. Или что мне нужно сделать? Я не совсем еще проффи в этих делах, по этому и спрашиваю! Как лучше будет сделать...